# Postgres JSON_AGG and Order By not working together

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT json_agg(deals.*) FROM deals WHERE vendors.id = deals.vendorid) as deals
FROM vendors
```

That query works great, however when I try and order by a field in the `deals` table like this:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT json_agg(deals.*) FROM deals WHERE vendors.id = deals.vendorid ORDER BY priority) as deals
FROM vendors
```

I get the following error:

```
error: column "deals.priority" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Any ideas how to do a sort like this?

Answer (score 44):

You can

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT json_agg(deals.* ORDER BY priority) FROM deals WHERE vendors.id = deals.vendorid) as deals
FROM vendors
```

See [examples with `array_agg` and `string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Comment: This works good, I feel like is shorter than the other option.

Comment: I’m surprised `WITHIN GROUP` works with `json_agg`…?

Comment: It seems like a bug, can't imagine any performance advantage by shuffling the query results, the aggregation (in my mind) was supposed to be a simple loop through the results, keeping the order-by of the select

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: It’s not a bug. `ORDER BY` happens after grouping; that’s how SQL semantics are defined.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't the syntax be this?

```
(SELECT json_agg(deals.*) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY priority)
 FROM deals
 WHERE vendors.id = deals.vendorid 
) as deals
```

The documentation is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Answer (score 3):

As a side note, if you don't limit the amount of deals queried, you should use a left join instead of a subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM vendors
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT vendorid, json_agg(* ORDER BY priority) AS deals
  FROM deals
  GROUP BY vendorid
)
ON vendors.id = deals.vendorid
```

Comment: As written isn't there a sub-query in your `LEFT JOIN`?! I think you'd want to use `LEFT JOIN deals ON vendors.id = deals.vendorid` and then have the `json_agg()` in the first `SELECT`....

Comment: It is a subquery, but it doesn't depend on the parent query and as such will only be evaluated once - and could also be moved to a CTE. In contrary, the subquery in the accepted answer uses the parent `vendors.id` and therefore has to be executed for every row, which you generally want to avoid.